# Удобочитаемый вид boolean поля в DBGridEh

Tags: dbgrid, delphi-7

Какое свойство необходимо редактировать у **DBGridEh** у boolean - поля, чтобы вместо true и false  выводились "Да" и "Нет"? DisplayFormat и KeyList не помогают (поля становятся вообще пустыми).

Answer (score 1):

Вы в KeyList добавляли 2 значения?

```
Да 
Нет
```

Со справки:

> Checkboxes automativcaly true for boolean field. To show checkboxes
>   for non boolean fields fill first line of KeyList that corresponds to
>   the checked state of the checkbox, second line - non checked state,
>   and set Checkboxes to True. Line of KeyList can represent more than
>   one value in a semicolon-delimited list of items.
>
> ```
>  DBGridEh1.Columns[1].KeyList.Strings[0] := 'True;Yes;On';
>  DBGridEh1.Columns[1].KeyList.Strings[1] := 'False;No;Off';
> ```
>
> For boolean field not need to fill keyList.

Еще знаю что в DBGrid можно было изменить значение с помощью 
изменения свойства столбца, может там есть что то похожее

```
DiaplayValues = Да;Нет
```

или

с помощью события для поля onGetText:

```
procedure TForm1.ADOTable1fieldGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: string;
  DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  if Sender.AsBoolean then 
    Text := 'Да'
  else 
    Text := 'Нет';
end;
```